# The Al Pacino Marlon Brando Pigeon Joke

Tags: reference, jack-and-jill

So I somehow ended up watching a youtube video called *Jack and Jill - Nostalgia Critic*, and at 14m15s ([clip](https://www.youtube.com/embed/djIIs2dkaX0?start=855&end=865)), a joke in the movie is given the spotlight.

> **Pacino**: I used to raise pigeons.
>
> **"Jill"**: Really?
>
> **Pacino**: Yeah... No, I'm sorry, that was Brando.

Which is met with a fake laugh from Doug, followed by praise what's warrant is questionable at best.

I don't get it. What do pigeons have to do with *The Godfather*? Does "pigeon" have a second, mafia-related meaning that I'm not aware of? How is this joke supposed to be funny?

Comment: Do you have a link to the video? That could help you get more answers and higher-quality answers.

Comment: @BrettFromLA [Yes](https://www.youtube.com/embed/djIIs2dkaX0?start=855&end=865). I initially refrained from adding it, as I figured it wouldn't be necessary with the quote and context. But since you asked, I went ahead and added it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'd forgotten that _Jack and Jill_ was a (bad) Adam Sandler movie. It's the kind of humor that Sandler would use.

Comment: Seems kinda redundant to use "Adam Sandler movie" and "bad" in the same sentence...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It's nothing to do with *The Godfather*.

I also question the humour in the joke but there's a couple of possible explanations.

The first is that they are playing with the audience and their expectations. Pacino and Brando are both major actors and even Pacino can't keep straight all the nutty things that are said about them.

The second is, perhaps, more likely and it's a reference to Brando's breakout role in *On The Waterfront*, where Brando's character **did** keep pigeons.

[image]

Comment: Ah, so it's a reference that lacks an actual punchline. I don't understand why people find those funny, but... fair enough.